# PHP Symfony SQL Queries button Missing from Toolbar

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

Hi am I am using Symfony to develop the Jobeet website while I try to learn it for a bigger project and it is going resonably well so far.

However I have just got to page 73 where it mentiones clicking on the SQL Query button to debug your queries generated, I don't seem to have this button, even on pages that are definately using SQL.

Databases.yml

```
all:
  propel:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobeet;'
      username: root
      password: password
      encoding: utf8
```

Does anyone know why it wouldn't be showing up?

Is there any more information I can provide to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you need something like this:

File: *config/databases.yml*

```
dev:
  propel:
    param:
      classname:    DebugPDO
```

Now, if you have `web_debug: on` in your application settings.yml (for the `dev` environment), it should work fine.

Comment: In my case, I had explicitly set the profiler option on the same level as classname to false.